# App engine - Naked domain redirect to "www"

Tags: domain-name-system, https, google-app-engine

I set up my domain with SSL certificate on Google Appengine: `https://www.ltc-x.de/`

Everything is working fine for the `www` subdomain.

Now I want to get the naked domain to work as well. So if someone types in just `ltc-x.de` they should be redirected to `www.ltc-x.de`,

I followed this instructions, but I always get an error when I try to save the forward:
[image]

The error in German is, “Serverfehler: Wir können ihre anfrage derzeit leider nicht bearbeiten, bitte versuchen Sie es später erneut.” Which in English translates to “Server Error: We can currently unable to process your request, please try again later.”

I already contacted the support, but they were not very helpful.

My A-records look like this:
[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Did someone experience similar behaviour and is there a way to get this working?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I missed one entry on the screenshot. It looks like this:

@BillThor: Are you sure I need an A and an AAAA entry for the www subdomain as well? Because currently I only have the CNAME entry for the www domain and it works.
[image]

Comment: Why the hell are your domains/subdomains empty?

Comment: Sorry, I missed one entry for the www subdomain. Added a complete screenshot now.

Answer (score 1):

For HTTPS you will need an alternate subject name for the bare domain on your SSL certificate.  This will prevent errors resulting from the certificate name not matching the requested domain.

In DNS you only need to ensure that the bare domain and your www domain have the same address(es) A and AAAA addresses.  Your snapshot of the DNS panel is missing the names.  For www and the bare domain (@), you need one A record and one AAAA record each.  www is the name for the www address.  You can use @ or the bare domain ending with a dot (example.com.) as the name for the bare domain.

Comment: Are you sure I need an A and AAAA for the www domain as well? See my updated question?

Comment: @jan You only need one, but if your have an IPv6 address, you need the AAAA record to enable access over IPv6.  We are not at the point were most people would want only an AAAA, which would disable access by most users who only have IPv4 addresses and access.